# Given that $x^3=x^2+x+1$ find $x^4$ in terms of $x^2$ and a constant.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I don't know is this *can* be done,  but I'm just interested in it, and I'm hoping that it is possible. Here's the question:

> Given that $x^3=x^2+x+1$ find $x^4$ in terms of $x^2$ and a constant.

I simply cannot seem to do it (and no, I don't mean something like $x^4=(x^2)^2$, I mean in terms of $x^2$ with some constant coeficcient :-) ) . The best I can do is show that $x^4=2x^3-1$, but nothing more.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This smells like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @KennyLau it is, sort of, but in this case I *know* that solving this would greatly help the solution of another problem I'm working on.

Comment: The fact that solving this would help you solve the problem you really care about is precisely what makes an XY problem. The route that took you to this question might not be a good way to attack the original problem. (@KennyLau)

Comment: @EthanBolker thank you for the interest! In this case though this is the only route for the problem I was looking at; I know that because I made the other problem up and its solvability depended on this being solvable :)

Comment: Well then perhaps the other problem is unsolvable. You might want to ask about it directly in another question (if you do, then link to this one).  Be sure to show us how far you can get and as much context as possible.

Comment: @EthanBolker I will consider it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^3=x^2+x+1$. Multiply by $x$: $x^4=x^3+x^2+x$. Replace $x^3$ by $x^2+x+1$: $x^4=2x^2+2x+1$. And I think that's as good as it gets, I don't see anyway to eliminate the linear term, without some further information.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way, are you the same Gerry Myerson as this Gerry Myerson? https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson

Comment: Yes, that's me.

Comment: As you have found this answer helpful, A-Level, you might consider "accepting" it, by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Of course, sorry about that. I forgot. Just out of curiosity, why have you made a new user? Your previous user had over 100k reputation!

Comment: One day, I lost access to that account, so I started a new one.

Comment: That's such a shame, have you contacted SO for help in accessing it?

Comment: Not yet. Eventually.